# TypeScript: Difference Generic Constraints VS Parameter Type

Tags: typescript, generics, parameters

I do not understand the difference between Generic Constraints and plain Parameter Types.
In the first case, I do understand that I cannot call si.g() because I strictly typed si to be of type SomeInterface. However, in the second example S extends SomeInterface and from my explanation , extending means it needs to have f() but can contain more properties. But the error is the same. Why?

```
interface SomeInterface {
    f();
}

function test1(si: SomeInterface) {
    si.f()
    // si.g() -> Property 'g' does not exist on type 'SomeInterface'
}

function test2<S extends SomeInterface>(si: S) {
    si.f()
    // si.g() -> Property 'g' does not exist on type 'SomeInterface'
}
```

Comment: `S extends SomeInterface` means `S` can be a subtype of `SomeInterface` but there is no guarantee that a subtype will have `g()`. It might be `interface OtherInterface extends SomeInterface { e(); }`

Comment: `S` can be any subtype of `SomeInterface` that the *caller* of the function wants it to be.  So the *implementer* of the function needs to write code that works for every possible specification of `S`, including just `SomeInterface` itself, which has no `g()` method.

Comment: @VLAZ yes there is no guarantee, even in interfaces that extend from SomeInterface.
Thats wyh in function test2, TS makes sure g() is found and throws an error, just like TS did in test1. But whats the difference then between test1 and test2 except the syntax?

Comment: @user3601578 in this case - nothing. The example code is just too trivial for generics.

Answer (score 1):

Typescript needs to check that you're passing a type that includes the function `g`.  So you need to do something like this:

```
interface ExtendedInterface extends SomeInterface {
 g();
}

...

function test2<E extends ExtendedInterface>(ei: E) {
    si.f()
    si.g()
}
```

Of course, you can also do this:

```
function test3(ei: ExtendedInterface) {
    ei.g();
    ei.f();
}
```

And that'll be functionally identical to the version with generics.

So what's the difference?  Nothing here, but generics give you more power at the expense of more complex code. For example, generics allow you to declare a type parameter that is constrained by another type parameter.

Comment: Thanks, but how is your code different to: 

function test2(ei: ExtendedInterface) {
    si.f()
    si.g()
}

Answer (score 0):

> ...extending means it needs to have f() but can contain more properties. But the error is the same. Why?

Because it **may** or may not have more properties, and if it does, they may have any name or any type. TypeScript doesn't know what those properties are, so inside `test2`, TypeScript only knows that `si` is a `SomeInterface`.

You opened by saying you didn't understand the difference between type parameters (`<S extends SomeInterface>` and `si: S`) vs. just putting types on parameters (`si: SomeInterface`). There's no real difference **in your specific example**; either way, TypeScript handles `si` as being of type `SomeInterface`. However, in the *general* case, type parameters let you do things you can't do just by typing parameters directly. Here's an example:

```typescript
function pluck<Type extends object, Key extends keyof Type>(array: Type[], key: Key) {
    return array.map(element => element[key]);
}

const objects = [{a: 2, b: "s"}, {a: 3, b: "x"}];
const x = pluck(objects, "a"); // `x` is `number[]`
const y = pluck(objects, "b"); // `y` is `string[]`
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABABwDYggawDwBUCeyApokQB5RFgAmAzonAEYBWR0ANIgNJH6kVU6iTLzjBEBYgD4AFAEMATgrn4AXBMJEA2gF1OItd14BKRAG8AUImuIFRKCAVJFy-ADoAtnOQyiqIh5UUIgAvFKk-oFgUFoGOsYA3BYAvhYWEAi0wUys0PQhiFpmcuoATJyM6gBEtFXJnMXqAMwV1WR1OkkZYFmIZKEo6FgyOWxQtJxVclWJiAD0c4gABmRLiDD0S2AgHoxECrpL6ZnBfAVoGJgjLGMTiFWMMwnzi0v4axvLWQowYADmhwsQA)

I could be mistaken, but I don't think you can do that without type parameters (or type assertions).

Comment: Thanks, but "extends objects" (also "extends {}") is extending from a nullish value and basically allows everything. Thats why it is blocked by current ESLint configurations.

Comment: @user3601578 - That was just an example, not the point of the answer, which was the concepts. If it bothers you, literally just remove those two words. (Also note that ESLint configs are **opinions**, not facts.)

Comment: Yes, given the fact the object and {} can have any keys and a key is ALWAYS a string, I can easily replace your generic function with: 

function pluck(array: object[], key: string) {
    return array.map(element => element[key]);
}

Comment: @user3601578 - Well, first off, [that doesn't work](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABABwDYggawBQEMBO+uAngFyJwBGAVgKbQDaAugDSKa1mIDOU+MYAOYBKRAG8AUImmJ8tKCHxICRYgDoAtrmTZaqWhtpgoiALwA+RHoNGoDDsSbCA3BIC+QA). But even if it did (if you changed `object` to, say, `Record<string, any>`, it wouldn't be typesafe. Type safety is the entire point of using TypeScript. If you don't want type safety, just write JavaScript code. (Also: Property keys are not always strings, even in JavaScript [Symbol], much less TypeScript which has the concept of string literal types and `keyof`.)

Comment: @user3601578 - I didn't change any playground defaults at all: I went to the playground and copied and pasted. And there is **zero** reason to be rude to people who are taking time to try to help you. *"If I switch on non-empty objects, I also get an error with your code."* What do you mean by that? Could you share a playground link? If there's a problem with the code, I want to know about it.

Comment: It's true that if I go in and turn off `noImplicitAny` your code no longer errors, but the type of the resulting arrays is `any[]`, which isn't useful. [Example](https://tsplay.dev/Wol5aw). I'm sorry if I've misunderstood the question. I have tried to understand it, and obviously my only reason for trying to help was, well, to try to help -- in this case, by pointing out a difference between the two things you seem to be asking about. Perhaps you could edit the question to clarify.